# Show that if $N=2^p -1$, $p$ prime, then $2^{N-1} \equiv 1$ mod $N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $N=2^p -1$, $p$ prime $\implies$  $2^{N-1} \equiv 1$ mod $N$

I thought about using Euler's Theorem: clearly $(2, 2^p -1)=1$, so $2^{\varphi (N)} \equiv 1$ mod $N$, which will finish the proof iff N is a prime.

Uh oh, $2^{11} -1$ is not prime, so this argument won't work.

Comment: I thought about using Euler's Theorem: clearly $(2, 2^p -1)=1$, so $2^{\varphi (N)} \equiv 1$ mod $N$, which will finish the proof iff N is a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to have $2^p\equiv 1\pmod{\! N}$. By Little Fermat $\frac{2^p-2}{p}=\frac{N-1}{p}$ is an integer.

$$2^p\equiv 1\pmod{\! N}\stackrel{\frac{N-1}{p}}\implies 2^{N-1}\equiv 1\pmod{\! N}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to showing that if $p$ is prime, then $2^p-1 \mid 2^{2^p-2}-1.$
It therefore suffices to prove that $p \mid 2^p-2$, which is a clear consequence of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Can you explain why it suffices to show $p|2^p-2$? Does it have something to do with the binomial theorem?

Comment: @futuremathteacher It is because $2^{ab}-1=\left(2^a-1\right)\left( 2^{ab-a}+2^{ab-a-1}+\cdots+ 2+1\right)$.

Comment: @futuremathteacher Btw, my answer uses this too, but in the form of Congruence Power Rule (which can be proved using this factorization). Also, as I said, $N\mid 2^p-1$ is enough. This is because if $N\mid 2^p-1\mid 2^{2^p-2}-1$, then $N\mid 2^{2^p-2}-1$.